# Windows installer self-healing using ProvideComponent

Tags: delphi, windows-installer

I have an application(app1) that uses another application(app2)'s DLL to do some things. The problem is that I need to have some current user registries set for the DLL to work. If I call app2 from the advertised shortcut it will invoke windows installer self-healing and populate its registries. However if I've just installed app2 from another user,logged in for the first time, and used app1 it will fail as the DLL will not have it's registries populated.

With this in mind I tried to use the [Self-Invoked Resiliency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302344.aspx) method to trigger MSI self-healing.

The "HKCU" feature is the top feature containing a single component "HCKURegistry" which only contains registry keys. The keypath for the "HCKURegistry" component is a key in the HKCU hive.

I'm using Delphi XE3 and here is the line of code:

```
szProductCode :='{293A0959-6ECF-4026-929B-ECC777934525}';
szComponent:=   '{45282475-634F-4222-81BA-030FA63703BD}' ;  
MsiProvideComponent(pwidechar(szProductCode),pwidechar('HKCU'),pwidechar(szComponent),INSTALLMODE_DEFAULT,  lpPathBuf,@pcchPathBuf);
```

When, however, my app1 executes this line the Windows Installer displays a windows installer "Preparing to install..." window and stays like this forever. If I click "Cancel" it says "Canceling..." and stays like this until I kill the app from the task manager.

The Event log shows two items:

```
Detection of product '{293A0959-6ECF-4026-929B-ECC777934525}', feature 'HKCU', component '{45282475-634F-4222-81BA-030FA63703BD}' failed.  
Detection of product '{293A0959-6ECF-4026-929B-ECC777934525}', feature 'HKCU' failed during request for component '{45282475-634F-4222-81BA-030FA63703BD}'
```

A possibly relevant information. When I trigger the self healing the normal way I get the same two lines but the second one has additional sentence (the keypath registry key for the component):

```
Detection of product '{293A0959-6ECF-4026-929B-ECC777934525}', feature 'HKCU', component '{45282475-634F-4222-81BA-030FA63703BD}' failed.  The resource 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyData\SomePath' does not exist.
```

I moments of desperation I tried using:

```
res:=MsiReinstallFeature(pwidechar(szProductCode),pwidechar('HKCU'),REINSTALLMODE_USERDATA);
```

And swapping INSTALLMODE_DEFAULT for REINSTALLMODE_USERDATA in the MsiProvideComponent call. Both behaved differenty in that they did not put anything into the Event log. Otherwise they both stuck in "Preparing to install..." just as the original call...

I'm stuck on this for a while now. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Will it be okay, if the settings app2's DLL needs would be created also for users that never run neither app1 nor app2 ? If so, then just use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components`

Comment: Personally I thought that default settings are to be set in HKLM and HKCU is for the user's custom **overrides** of defaults. Thus since your new user did not run app2 and did not overrode anything in it, app2 (including the dll) should just operate on defaults in HKLM, why not ?

Comment: The article you linked to suggests to call `MsiQueryProductState( {app2} szProductCode)` before checking the features to see if it is installed - did you do it? If windows considered app2 not installed for the new user, then perhaps it is not reasonable to check for features of non-installed application.

Comment: Yes, I do call MsiQueryProductState. Not that it matters, since I know the outcome of it because I installed the app myself.

Comment: you installed app1 into this user, and app2 was installed under a different one. Maybe that matters. Anyway, why not use old good ActiveSetup then ?

Comment: In the end I did use ActiveSetup. But I still need to know why it did not work. I spent almost 2 days sifting through this and I do not want it to be for naught.

Comment: the only clean way for msi repairs (or advertisement or self-resilency, they are basically all the same mechanism) to work is to have everything in one MSI. if your app has a shortcut make it advertised, place it in the same component as the HKCU regkeys, make one of the regkeys the keypath. if the shortcut is triggered the installer checks all keypaths, doesnt find it and trigger a full repair.